# Segmentation fault in C associated with array and printing array in correct way

Tags: c

I want to implement this 
ls -l | myprogram.

Myprogram takes output of pipe as an input and get every word into array.
then I print out array line by line so that in each line 8 words.

I wrote a code but it gives segmentation fault and does not print my array of of words. What is wrong here? Beginner here....

```
    #include <stdio.h>
    #include <string.h>
    int main(int argc, char **argv){

    int result,i;
    int j=0;
    char string[80];   
    char  wordArray [80];


    do {    
           result=scanf("%s",string);

           strcpy(wordArray[j], string);
           printf("%s\n", wordArray[j]);
           j++;

    }
           while (result!=EOF);

    for (i=0; i<7;i++){
    printf("%s ",wordArray[i]);

   }                   
    return 0;
 }
```

Comment: The variable wordArray is a string just like the variable string.  If you want it to be an array of strings you need a two dimensional array, something like: char wordArray[1000][80]

Comment: There are no "array of words" declared in your program.  You have an array of char.

Comment: You are trying to read a string and then copying it in to a array which does not have enough space to store it.

Answer (score 2):

At least this function call is invalid

```
strcpy(wordArray[j], string);
```

Argument `wordArray[j]` has type `char` while the first parameter of the function has type `char *`

You have to define an array of arrays of characters. For example

```
char  wordArray[7][80];
```

provided that the number of entered strings does not exceed 7.

Take into account that the second loop should look like

```
for ( i = 0; i < j; i++ ){
```

Also the first loop is invalid because though the result in the last iteration of the loop is equal to EOF nevertheless you try to copy non-entered string `string` in the array (as the result is equal to EOF then it means that nothing was entered. So the last valid string will be copied twice)

Answer (score 1):

wordArray is only 1 dimension.  Try adding [8][80]

http://www.tutorialspoint.com/cprogramming/c_multi_dimensional_arrays.htm